# Alternative for SortedSet<T> in Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, portable-class-library

Are there any alternatives in PCL for [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd412070(v=vs.100).aspx)? Or must I implement my own?

I need an indexed list of non-duplicated strings that I can search through within a PCL that supports .NET 4.0. My current workaround is to rely on a `List<T>` object, call its `Sort` method and use `BinarySearch` method. It works, but I was hoping I could do better.

Comment: If you go to the [newer version of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll find that PCL/Windows Phone/Windows Store is supported.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Thanks for pointing this out. However I need to support .NET 4.0. I updated the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. As far as I can tell, you're out of luck and you'll either have to use third party solution or roll out your own implementation...

Comment: What about a *set* do you need?  Or, are you looking just for a sorted collection?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I do want a collection that is sorted so I can make quick, efficient searches on it. The list must also not contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "Sorted" collections in that PCL profile.  So, you'd either have to call the `Sort` method on another collection to get it sorted or write your own sorted collection.  If all you need is a collection, you could use a simple binary search/insertion to sort items as they are added to the collection.  An example using a backing `List<T>` might look like this:

```
public class SortedCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> collection = new List<T>();
    // TODO: initializable:
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
            return;
        }
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = collection.Count - 1;

        while (minimum <= maximum)
        {
            int midPoint = (minimum + maximum) / 2;
            int comparison = comparer.Compare(collection[midPoint], item);
            if (comparison == 0)
            {
                return; // already in the list, do nothing
            }
            if (comparison < 0)
            {
                minimum = midPoint + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                maximum = midPoint - 1;
            }
        }
        collection.Insert(minimum, item);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        // TODO: potential optimization
        return collection.Contains(item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        // TODO: potential optimization
        return collection.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        collection.Clear();
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count { get { return collection.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
}
```

I've done the minimum to get a sorted collection that is functional.  You can optimize so that `Contains` and `Remove` recognize the list is sorted and do a O(log n) search instead of a an O(n)...

There are other algorithms that might be faster; but without much more to go on, I chose a simple and well understood algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, renamed to `SortedCollection` as it doesn't implement `ISet<T>` (nor could it)