# In what PCL profile, if any, does SortedList<K, V> exist?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, base-class-library

After creating a PCL class library in VS2015 with targets .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, and ASP.NET Core 5.0 (Profile 7) I expected to be able to reference `SortedList<K, V>` but it's not available. All the other generic containers seem to have been retained so I'm wondering if MS posted somewhere why this particular container was dropped. And, more generally, how I figure out which of these targets is preventing me access to a type `SortedList<K, V>`.

Comment: [See Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976022/alternative-for-sortedsett-in-portable-class-library)

Comment: None of them, it is only implemented in the full desktop version.  So isn't portable at all.  Readily visible from the MSDN docs, look at the "Version Information" annotation at the bottom.  Compare to SortedDictionary which did make it into .NETCore.  These choices are quite intentional for a reason that the team does not often share.  Knowing the answer does not help you solve this problem at all anyway.

Comment: Ah, I was only looking at the version information at the top of the MSDN documentation. Didn't check to see if there was another version information section at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version section at the bottom of the MSDN docs tells you if the type is .NET Core.